# Пользователь без пароля

Tags: ubuntu

Как создать учетную запись без пароля, чтобы при работе под рутом, можно было выполнять скрипты от пользователя с меньшими правами, не тратя время на ввод пароля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких вещей есть /etc/sudoers - список того, что кто из пользователей может делать. Сначала добавляем пользователя:

```
sudo adduser anybody
```

Затем открываем на редактирование список sudoers

```
sudo visudo
```

И добавляем в список запись

> `%from ALL=(to) NOPASSWD: ALL`

где from - имя пользователя, от которого передается управление, а to - имя пользователя, которому передается управление. Теперь при необходимости выполнить команду от имени to

```
sudo -u to echo hello
```